# Installing Windows over Ubuntu 22.04 - No Partitions shown

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a Predator (PO3-640) PC.

I had windows 11 installed on it.
Using a bootable USB, I installed Ubuntu 22.04 over that Windows 11 install.
Now, I want to overwrite Ubuntu with Windows 11 again (I do this to fully wipe the drive when I think there's a virus), but I get the following error when using the Bootable Windows USB (created with MediaCreationTool).

Boot Mode in the BIOS is UEFI.
I have set the install media (USB) to be GPT.

[image: no Partitions]

What do I need to do to create/overwrite the partition with Windows?

I tried following these instructions: https://community.acer.com/en/kb/articles/13832-hard-disk-not-detected-during-windows-10-installation

I am able to select my driver to load it, but still no new disks/partitions show to install windows to.

Thank you!

Comment: `I do this to fully wipe the drive when I think there's a virus` ... how does that wipe the drive?

Comment: "We couldn't find any drivers ..." typically happens for one reason, the HDD is formatted as MBR or GPT while the system is configured to boot Legacy or UEFI.  MBR can only be used in Legacy mode while GPT can only be used with UEFI. **Windows 11 only supports UEFI.** [Edit] your question to indicate if Legacy (CSM) is enabled or disabled.  If you are trying to install Windows 11 it should be disabled. **Intel RST should be disabled unless you have multiple drives and are going to be using them in a RAID configuration.**

Comment: @Ramhound I have updated the question to the best of my knowledge. The boot mode is UEFI, I saw no Legacy(CSM)  setting so I imagine it is disabled. I re-created my boot media as GPT, but still have the same error.

Comment: @Dreki - Did you disable Intel RST? If you have it enabled you have to provide an Intel RST driver.

Comment: @Ramhound it shows my two drives as "Non-Raid" and VMD controlled, I left that as default. IRST is not enabled.

Comment: Why did you link you an article about Intel RST if your not using it? What’s VMD in this context?

Comment: @Ramhound Admittedly, I am a newb - I tried the IRST and the VMD drivers from the manufacturer's website. Adding both to the USB drive as a folder alongside the install media. I linked the article for IRST because it included the steps for adding the drivers to the install media flash drive.